# Gtk::ScaleButton: Icons in the constructor

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am trying to use a Gtk::ScaleButton in Gtkmm 3. My problem is the constructor. It needs as last parameter (see here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1ScaleButton.html#a96753b6cb6b8adb0ed3727ba3eb8cfb7 ) a vector of ustrings. I guess (i can't find it in the docs what it means exactly) i have to give it the path to the +/- Images. I want to use the Gtk Stock items for +/-. How can i achieve this?

Currently i give it an empty vector, which results in a glibmm warning:

```
    std::vector<Glib::ustring> icons;
    Gtk::ScaleButton * scale = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::ScaleButton(Gtk::ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR, 0.0, 10.0, 1.0, icons));
```

Warning:

```
 glibmm-WARNING **: Glib::ConstructParams::ConstructParams(): object class "gtkmm__GtkScaleButton" has no property named "min"
```

How can i avoid the warning and give it stock icons?

Comment: [Description of the icons array.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScaleButton.html#GtkScaleButton--icons) The raw GTK+ constructor says this can be empty; I'm not sure what that means for gtkmm. You can use [standard icon names](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) for these if you so choose. I don't know about your specific issue, though... it sounds like something else is going wrong

Comment: The ScaleButton constructor is incomplete in gtkmm itself. I will try to fix it there. In the meantime, you can try using: Gtk::ScaleButton* button = Glib::wrap(gtk_scale_button_new(whatever));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be one of the first people to ever try using this Gtk::ScaleButton constructor from gtkmm. It seems to have been broken for several years.

I've fixed it in gtkmm: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/commit/?id=26f94d231da9481d74acdd94e56168ed6b38609a

But it will be some time until that is widely available via Linux distro packages. In the meantime you can try using

```
Gtk::ScaleButton* button = Glib::wrap(gtk_scale_button_new(whatever));
```

See https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-gobj-and-wrap.html.en

However, I don't know how it's actually meant to behave, so you might encounter other bugs. You might actually want to use the derived Gtk::VolumeButton instead.

andlabs is correct that the GTK+ documentation describes the icons better:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScaleButton.html#GtkScaleButton--icons
and those should indeed probably be the standard icon names:
http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Ill try using it from the repo directly (i am on gentoo linux, so it shouldnt be a problem at all). Ill report back later if its working properly

Comment: I've also added some example code to prove to myself that it works now:
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm-documentation/tree/examples/book/buttons/scalebutton